# Adobe air mobile getPageContent and decode it using json

Tags: json, actionscript-3, air, file-get-contents

I am trying to make a flash iPhone app that communicates with a website that I created, i should get the information in JSON... But I can't find a function that allow me to do it in air.

Is there any way of getting a page content and decode JSON in flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Get Page Content

Simple example for `GET` in `google.com`.

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://google.com/");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function( e:Event ):void
{
    trace( e.currentTarget.data );
});
urlLoader.load( req );
```

### JSON Decode

Use `try...catch` for the safe.

```
try
{
    JSON.parse(e.currentTarget.data);
}catch( e:Error )
{
    trace(e.message);
}
```